# Авторизация в Телеграм боте на Python с библиотекой aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Новичок в программировании и никак не могу понять как реализовать авторизацию по логину и паролю в боте

Comment: добавьте пример кода

Answer (score 0):

Логином может выступать id пользователя, а пароль может запрашиваться при запуске бота - то есть по команде `/start`. Прикрутите базу данных (например Sqlite3) и  будет Вам счастье